# Ms Excel - I cannot open my database sheet, but the pivot sheets shows data extracted from database

Tags: excel, windows

I cannot open my database sheet, but the other sheets shows the data. Get the error: "Can't open PivotTable source file"

For exemple I have the A database sheet. B and C pivot sheets show the data extracted from the database.

But my database sheet is empty. What can I do to recover (to see) my database again?

Comment: If your pivot table has a Grand Total Row, double click on Grand Total Value, it will create a new sheet with a table having the whole data set for you. You can then move that sheet to a New workbook and save it if required. If Grand Total is not visible, go to the Pivot Table's Design tab and add the Grand Total.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked. I have added it as an Answer, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pivot table has a Grand Total Row, double click on Grand Total Value, it will create a new sheet with a table having the whole data set for you. You can then move that sheet to a New workbook and save it if required. If Grand Total is not visible, go to the Pivot Table's Design tab and add the Grand Total.